# How to read/interpret complicated expressions in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, expression

Something like this:

```
int ctr[], i, distinct = 0;

string s;

distinct += ctr[s[i]]++ == 0; // <-- This line
```

I understand the notations of array and what increment and decrement operators are. I just don't understand the way to write like this. More importantly, the purpose of writing like this.

Comment: Did somebody write this code `distinct += ctr[s[i]]++ == 0`- Go out and shout him

Comment: Looks like some code got obfuscated because of source-level optimization. I suppose a good compiler would do similar thing on AST/Assembly level.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Is it defined behavior? Where are the sequence points? It is crap code. Delete it and rewrite

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @EdHeal Agreed, but let he who is without sin... I do remember one of M$'s early compilers (V5.0, I think) getting *ptr++ wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like the following code:

```
char c = s[i];
distinct = distinct + ctr [x]; // "value +=" is the same as "value = value + ..."

ctr[c]++; // char is used as number here. The c. element in ctr[] is incremented.
//because of c++ instead of ++c the increment is done after all.
distinct == 0 // returns a boolean value into nirvana :)
```

I hope this will help you.

But if you want to code, you shouldn't write code like this. Especially if you want to read your code in future or want others to read it ;-)

Comment: Please read about operator precedence. Incrementation is done first. The comparison is the last operation. Your answer is incorrect

Comment: Yup it is a little bit to late tonight, sorry, you're right!

Comment: now it makes a different error (same error as the other answer) -- the result of `==` is what is added to `distinct`

Comment: Then my first answer was right? Now i will try it tomorrow to get sure!

Comment: The first answer was closer, but it used post-increment instead of pre-increment